# How can I parse Twitter API dates into java.time.Instant?

Tags: java, time, java-time, datetime-parsing

I am trying to parse the dates that come from the Twitter API into the new `Instant` class from Java 8. FYI, this is the format `Wed Aug 09 17:11:53 +0000 2017`.

I don't want to deal with / set a time zone, as one is specified in the string already. I just want an `Instant` instance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the solution

```
Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse(dateStr))
```

Comment: Are you sure this parses the string `Wed Aug 09 17:11:53 +0000 2017`?

Comment: I get `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Wed Aug 09 17:11:53 +0000 2017' could not be parsed at index 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [documentation of `DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss X uuuu", Locale.ROOT);
    Instant asInstant = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateStr, dtf).toInstant();
```

With your example string the result is an `Instant` of

```
2017-08-09T17:11:53Z
```

It seems from the [Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object) that offset will always be `+0000`. Depending on how strongly you trust this to be the case, you may use small `x` or capital `Z` instead of capital `X` in the format pattern. If you want stricter validation, you may also check that the `OffsetDateTime`’s  `.getOffset().equals(ZoneOffset.UTC)` yields true before you convert to `Instant`.